# How to produce react bundle.js through webpack via server.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Express server is up on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack  = require('webpack');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({

});
// const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'Main.js'),
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'],
                plugin

s: ["react-html-attrs"]
            }
        }
        , {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
    },
     {




test: /masonry|imagesloaded|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/,
    loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false&this=>window'
        },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },

        {
         test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractSass

    ],


 resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
}
};
```

I am trying to deploy on Heroku But before that when I run on cmd through npm start it starts on localhost but say **Cannot GET /** and nothing else runs but when I pass on cmd webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js it runs on localhost 8080 and works fine! I need to add serve.js before deploying on heroku what I am missing?

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `Procfile`? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile

Comment: web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Comment: I was missing app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
}); before .listen I have added this, but now localhost is running but nothing of UI is getting there on DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a file named `Procfile` that includes `web: <command to run your project>`. That command might be `node server.js` or something else dependent on Webpack, which has a [Production Guide here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/) (possibly `webpack -p`).